# Devise form rendered twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I follow devise tutorial. I edit the form same as the tutorial said and I see it rendered twice.

https://www.sitepoint.com/devise-authentication-in-depth/

I can't reply it.

```
<% header "Sign Up" %>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
    <% if @validatable %>
      <span class="help-block"><%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum</span>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Here is my view. I didn't mess with controller.

Comment: It is more preferable to debug the code here without leaving SO. So can you post some of your code here related to the issue ? like the particular controller and view.

Comment: Edited now. I am sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize, it happens to many.

Comment: I suspect this issue has something to do with `turbolinks` if you have that, then try removing `//= require turbolinks` from `application.js`

Answer (score 0):

I think I did something wrong with my template. It's fixed.